# How to get code coverage for independent if conditions in for loop using test class in salesforce?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, if

I need help to get 100%  code coverage for below trigger.This trigger will prevent me creating duplicate record.

```
   trigger DuplicateTriggerReseller on Reseller_Details__c (before insert) {
    for(Reseller_Details__c reseller : [SELECT Mobile__c,Email__c,Phone__c from Reseller_Details__c ]){
        //Fetching details from Reseller_Details__c and putting in -->Reseller_Details__c reseller
        for(Reseller_Details__c r : trigger.new){//It will have newly entered data
            //Checking  for duplicates here
            if(reseller.Name==r.Name)
                r.Name.adderror('Duplicate Name');
            if(reseller.Mobile__c == r.Mobile__c )
                r.Mobile__c.adderror('Duplicate mobile');
            if(reseller.Email__c == r.Email__c)
                r.Email__c.adderror('Duplicate Email');
            if(reseller.Phone__c == r.Phone__c)
                r.Phone__c.adderror('Duplicate phone');
           
        }
    }    
}
```

When i have written Test class i got code coverage of 30%. I have written below test class.Please help me on this. I appreciate your helpPlease!

**Test class**

```
@isTest
public class DuplicateTriggerResellerTestClass {
    static testMethod void method1(){
        Reseller_Details__c rd=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd.Name='EliteCoders';
        rd.Mobile__c='111111111';
        rd.Email__c='shaik@gmail.com';
        rd.Phone__c='122344566';
        rd.Address__c='India';
        insert rd;
        Test.startTest();
        Reseller_Details__c rd1=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd1.Name='EliteCoders';
        rd1.Mobile__c='888888888';
        rd1.Email__c='shaik.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd1.Phone__c='12345677';
        rd1.Address__c='Saudi Arabia';
        insert rd1;
        Test.stopTest();        
    }
    static testMethod void method2(){
        Reseller_Details__c rd2=new Reseller_Details__c();
                rd2.Mobile__c='555555555';
        rd2.Name='EliteCoders';
        rd2.Email__c='shaik.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd2.Phone__c='9876544321';
        rd2.Address__c='Saudi Arabia';
        insert rd2;
                Test.startTest();
        Reseller_Details__c rd1=new Reseller_Details__c();
                rd1.Mobile__c='12234556';

        rd1.Name='EliteCoders1';
        rd1.Email__c='shaik.@gmail.com';
        rd1.Phone__c='1224357764';
        rd1.Address__c='Saudi';
        insert rd1;
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
    static testMethod void method3(){
        Reseller_Details__c rd=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd.Name='EliteCoder';
        rd.Mobile__c='222222222';
        rd.Email__c='shaik.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd.Phone__c='87665433211';
        rd.Address__c='Saudi Arabia';
        insert rd;
                Test.startTest();
        Reseller_Details__c rd1=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd1.Name='EliteCode';
        rd1.Mobile__c='700000001';
        rd1.Email__c='shaik.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd1.Phone__c='777777777';
        rd1.Address__c='Arabia';
        insert rd1;
        Test.stopTest();        
    }
    static testMethod void method4(){
        Reseller_Details__c rd=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd.Name='Elite';
        rd.Mobile__c='999999997';
        rd.Email__c='shaik.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd.Phone__c='88888888';
        rd.Address__c='Saudi Arabia';
        insert rd;
        Test.startTest();
        Reseller_Details__c rd1=new Reseller_Details__c();
        rd1.Name='EliteCoders';
        rd1.Mobile__c='7777777771';
        rd1.Email__c='moha.ghouse@gmail.com';
        rd1.Phone__c='6666666505';
        rd1.Address__c='Saudi Arabia';
        insert rd1;
        Test.stopTest();        
    }    
}
```

when i have used multiple test methods not able to get code coverage.

Comment: This trigger is disastrously inefficient and will cause limit exceptions very quickly. Use native Duplicate Management instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to salesforce David  I am not aware of native Duplicate Management

Comment: Trailhead will get you started: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management